# Remove ASPX FILE Extention in Web.config But Negate Rewrite if URL Contains Period

Tags: asp.net, regex, url, url-rewriting, web-config

All right, so by now most of us probably use the standard rule below for remove the aspx extention in your urls.

```
<rule name="Remove">
      <!--Removes the .aspx extension for all pages.-->
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx" />
    </rule>
```

However I would like to modify the rule to prevent the write rule from catching any url with a period in it.

That way if someone tries to type in http://www.domain.com/picture.jpg
The rule doesn't catch it.

Luckily the IsFile and IsDirectory conditions prevent actual files from being hit by the rule but whenever I have a case where someone types in a file that doesn't exist on the server then the rule catches it and asp.net does something like this:

http://www.domain.com/404error.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/picture.jpg.aspx

Id like it to not pass through the rule when there is a file not found.

Basically I just need to be able to add a condition that negates whenever a period is found in the url after the domain name. I'm assuming some sort of REGEX will work. I can't seem to get it working right though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come up with the following solution.

```
        <rule name="RewriteASPX" stopProcessing="true" enabled="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.aspx" matchType="IsFile" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx" />
        </rule>
```